# Evil surround repeat varying on varying width text possible?

Tags: evil

I use viws" (visual select word surround with double quote) quite a lot then move up and hit . to repeat is there a way to modify dot so it does the exact command again.

currently if i do the above to surround a 4 character word it works i move up a line then hit dot on a 6 character word however it inserts the " as if its a 4 character word instead of surrounding the whole word.

Is this a limitation of using dot or something you can configure ?

also open to other options of surrounding strings like this quickly.

Comment: The dot-command does not seem to be easily modifiable. Another option would be to define this as a macro (using `q` to do it the evil-way, or using `F3` and `F4` to do it the Emacs-way), and call the macro on every word you want to surround.

Comment: okay thanks, something i have not looked into much macros yet i will give it a try

Comment: This sounds more like a problem with evil-surround (wouldn't be the first time its repetition functionality broke).  If I do a change involving `M-f`, repeating it works correctly with words of varying width.

Comment: I reported it as an error, turns out i should be using ysiw" (you surround inner word ") then repeat works.

Comment: discussion on github https://github.com/emacs-evil/evil-surround/issues/124